# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for array

Tags: java, arrays

the statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = new int[ 3 ];
    for( int j = 0; j <= 3; j++ )
        System.out.println( a[j] );
}
```

gives me this:

0
0
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Untitled.main(Untitled.java:7)

Why is that so?

Comment: Try debugging. How far does `j` go? And how big is your array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are 0-based so a 3-element array includes 3 elements, numbered `0`, `1`, and `2`. For an array with `n` elements they are numbered `0` to `n-1`. Use:

```
 for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
```

instead.

Or better, don't hardcode:

```
for( int j = 0; j < a.length; j++ )
```

Comment: Thanks, hard to believe I looked over that. And can someone tell me why I'm downvoted? Was it my question?

Comment: @tantantheman Probably because people have seen this issue many times and get tired of it. I don't mind, and I didn't downvote. Anyway, can you click the checkmark to the left of my answer if it helped?

Comment: I will as soon as it'll let me! 9 Minutes to go. And thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing index of the array by 1 too many. Change your loop:

```
for( int j = 0; j <= 3; j++ )
```

to:

```
for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
```

Array indices are 0-based. So, the accessible indices for an array of size `n` are - `0`, `1`, `2`, ..., `(n - 1)`. Also, you should base your condition on the array length, and not hard-code it:

```
for( int j = 0; j < a.length; j++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[] = new int[ 3 ];
```

Will be there a[3]? No, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

When doing

```
new int[3]
```

you allocate / request only 3 memory 'slots', but the range [0, 3] has four numbers

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2
4. 3

so when `j == 3` you request the slot with number 4 (aka index 3) the program will not be able to find it, since you have reserved only 3, so it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`!